# Fetch records based on currency

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have table of tickets and each ticket has a price. I have set the base in database as USD, let say someone wants to purchase a ticket from a country other than US, I want to show prices to users in their local currency. What would be the appropriate approach. First I though I could convert the prices of tickets to local currency at run time, but this operation would be costly as tickets can be large in numbers.

For currency conversion I am using [Open Exchange Rates API](https://docs.openexchangerates.org/), I need to provide prices based on the currency provided through `req.query`.

I cant't show the actual code here but I have a sample:

```
const express = require('express');
const Product = require('../models/Product');
const { fetchRates } = require('../services/fx_rates')

const router = new express.Router();

router.post('/products', async (req, res) => {

    const product = new Product({
        ...req.body
    });

    try {
        await product.save();
        res.status(201).send(product);
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(400).send(e);
    }
});

router.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.find()
        // if (req.query.to) {
        //     for (let product of products) {
        //         fetchRates(product.price, 'USD', to)
        //             .then(price => {
        //                 product.price = price
        //             })
        //             .catch(e => console.log(e))

        //     }
        // }
        console.log(products)
        res.status(200).send({ products: products })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @AndrewL64 please check update question

Comment: Have you tried testing server side conversion right before you send the data? You can use axios/fetch in the server exactly in the same way you use it in the client side!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo I had a similar approach in my mind but then thought wouldn't it be expensive in terms of performance? I have decided to just send current conversion rates and client will do the calculations to show prices in relevant currency.

Comment: Sure that’s what I would do as well but in the question you wanted to avoid that so i proposed a different approach! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be to get the conversion rate with respect to USD for the required local currency and then convert the prices using the code instead of API. You can use the [open exchange latest.json endpoint](https://docs.openexchangerates.org/docs/latest-json) for it.
Here is an example.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function getConversionRate(localCurrency, base = 'USD'){
  const options = {
    uri: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json',
    qs: {
      app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      base: base,
      symbols: localCurrency,
    },
    json: true
  };
  const result = await rp(options);
  /*
  {
    disclaimer: "https://openexchangerates.org/terms/",
    license: "https://openexchangerates.org/license/",
    timestamp: 1449877801,
    base: "USD",
    rates: {
        INR: 71.43
    }
  }
  */
  return result.rates[localCurrency];
}

router.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [products, conversionRate] = await Promise.all([Product.find(), getConversionRate(req.query.to)])
        const convertedProducts = products.map(p => {
          p.price = p.price * conversionRate;
          return p;
        });
        console.log(convertedProducts)
        res.status(200).send({ products: convertedProducts })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I had an approach like this in my mind but the operation is costly in terms of performance, so I will be sending just conversion rates and client will convert the prices accordingly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the number of products being fetched per request on average?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  nodejs-currency-converter npm.

Comment: currency conversion is not the problem, I want to show the products to users in their local currency. Operation becomes time consuming when their are multiple records.

Comment: Then u can use the client-side.